# Kill what ever is running on port 8080

Tags: macos, process, port, localhost

I am trying to run a GAE app on `localhost:8080`, but it was apparently occupied, even after shutting down and restarting my computer. I ran `sudo lsof -i :8080`. Lo and behold there is something sill running with PID 66. What can I do to kill that process and free up 8080 again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out it's just `kill -9 PID`, you might need `sudo`. Found the answer on maclife.com in the article [Terminal 101: Track and Kill Processes](http://www.maclife.com/article/columns/terminal_101_track_and_kill_processes).

Answer (score 10):

1. Find out what Process ID (pid) is using the required port (e.g port `5434`).

   ```
   ps aux | grep 5434
   ```
2. Kill that process:

   ```
   kill -9 <pid>
   ```

Comment: See also [When should I not kill -9 a process?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/when-should-i-not-kill-9-a-process)

Comment: What in the output of the first command is the `pid`?

Answer (score 10):

`lsof -i @localhost:8080`

`kill -9 <<PID>>`

Comment: While this may work, it repeats what the OP posted and could use an explanation.

Comment: This answer is the most clear and has best feedback in terminal! `ps aux | grep 5434` doesn't say at all which is the PID!!

Comment: Nothing happens when I enter `lsof -i @localhost:8080`

Answer (score 6):

Merging answers from above in one line: `kill $(lsof -t -i:8080)`

`lsof -t` returns the PID and passes that to `kill`.

Comment: kill: not enough arguments

Comment: @MattWest that usually means that there isn't a process running on 8080.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open source project dedicated to this task.

https://github.com/jkfran/killport

You can install it and then run:

```
killport 8080
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command to find the process ID of the process running on the desired port:

```
$ netstat -ano | findstr :8080
```

The result will be displayed as:

```
$ netstat -ano | findstr :5000
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       18024
```

Here, 18024 is the PID or Process ID.

Then use the following command to kill the process on the post 8080:

```
$ taskkill /PID 18024 /F
```

or:

```
$ taskkill //PID 18024 //F
```

Result will be displayed as:

```
$ taskkill //PID 18024 //F
SUCCESS: The process with PID 18024 has been terminated.
```